# Swapped from Mint to Ubuntu and now cannot copy from/to my data drives

Tags: hard-drive, sharing

I just changed from Mint to Ubuntu.  Ubuntu works fine but I cannot copy to/from my 2 data drives.  I have 1 ssd with the system (250gb) 1 tb drive and 1 3 tb drive.  I can mount the data drives.  I can open data files from them but I cannot copy files from them or to them.  I'm still a newb here :(  I am having a terrible time uploading a screen shot from a terminal run...need help with two things!

```
 tc@Hezekiah:~$ lsblk -f
NAME           FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
loop0          squash                                                 /snap/core
loop1          squash                                                 /snap/gnom
loop2          squash                                                 /snap/gnom
loop3          squash                                                 /snap/gnom
loop4          squash                                                 /snap/core
loop5          squash                                                 /snap/gtk-
loop6          squash                                                 /snap/core
loop7          squash                                                 /snap/gnom
loop8          squash                                                 /snap/gnom
sda                                                                   
├─sda1         ext4            c966426e-32f2-40c4-b4d5-3cbb9e3d46f9   /boot
├─sda2                                                                
└─sda5         crypto          c0ebf290-760f-4e3f-a696-973cf1858c77   
  └─sda5_crypt LVM2_m          r3PpcY-qSn5-loRz-9Ul1-V3IH-Q3au-lyYD6g 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root
    │          ext4            1874f14e-6810-468a-856b-91881b0e8eca   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
               swap            3f112770-46a0-41ff-bcff-1488d57c0975   [SWAP]
sdb                                                                   
└─sdb1         ext4            00f6cb90-3ac2-4c36-9cdf-683572026558   
sdc                                                                   
├─sdc1                                                                
└─sdc2         ntfs   Tom 3 TB C0BA2E79BA2E6BDA
```

When I try to copy to or move to I get "error the destination is read only.

```
tc@Hezekiah:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3863824k,nr_inodes=965956,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=780220k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=44,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=17604)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-calculator_544.snap on /snap/gnome-calculator/544 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_399.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/399 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_127.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1440.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1668.snap on /snap/core18/1668 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8592.snap on /snap/core/8592 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8689.snap on /snap/core/8689 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_116.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_81.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/81 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/121 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=780216k,mode=700,uid=121,gid=125)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=780216k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdc2 on /media/tc/Tom 3 TB type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/tc/00f6cb90-3ac2-4c36-9cdf-683572026558 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: You forgot to include why you can not copy files. Make sure you own the partition or otherwise use "sudo"

Comment: "Make sure you own the partition or otherwise use "sudo" "  Please elaborate.  I have used Mint for a year basically by turning it on and using the gui :(

Comment: Please add the output of "mount". How did you stop Mint? If you didn't really shut it down the filesystems of the data drives could still be marked "busy"..

Comment: No, did not shut the filesystems down.